# Segmentation fault (core dump) while training a Hugging Face model

Tags: linux, huggingface-transformers, machine-translation

I am trying to train a Machine Translation model from HuggingFace (t5-large) using the europarl_bilingual dataset.
When I execute the code in my Linux GPU it goes without error until it downloads the model in

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, DataCollatorForSeq2Seq, Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
```

It performs the download, but when calling the model it throws the error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I faced the same error while importing the tokenizer but I found the solution here [ImportError when from transformers import BertTokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67636846/importerror-when-from-transformers-import-berttokenizer)
by downgrading the tokenizer version to:

```
conda install -c huggingface tokenizers=0.10.1 transformers=4.6.1
```

I tried keeping the tokenizer version to 0.10.1 and upgrading the transformers version to the latest for linux = 4.11.3 but the same error.

Do you have any idea what might be happening or how to fix it?

Thanks,